# How to turn on/off page numbering when merging PDF files

Tags: page-numbering, pdfpages

I am trying to merge separate PDF files, following this [advice](http://chongyangma.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/merge-pdf-files-using-latex/).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdfmerge{file1.pdf,-}
\includepdfmerge{file2.pdf,1-3}
\end{document}
```

Now I would like to keep the page numbering as it is in file 1. File 2 has no page numbering so I would manually set the counter and turn on page numbering. I tried

```
\setcounter{page}{25} 
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

but it didn't help: the page numbering didn't appear.

How can I turn on/off page numbering when merging separate PDF files?

---

Sad news: the url-s break down too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pagecommand` option as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdfmerge[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}}]{template.pdf,1-3}
\setcounter{page}{25}
\includepdfmerge[pagecommand={\pagestyle{plain}}]{template.pdf,-}
\end{document}
```

Adjust the values appropriately.

In this example, watch the fourth page and that has page number of 25.

[image]