# URL-s are broken after merging PDF files

Tags: hyperref, pdfpages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to preserve hyperlinks in included pdf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14620/how-to-preserve-hyperlinks-in-included-pdf)

After I merge PDF documents with `pdflatex` and `pdfpages` as [described here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77751/8599), the URL-s are either broken (PDF files from OpenOffice), or their colorbox is missing (`hyperref`), or if they span over two lines only the information from the first line is kept (the original PDF was correct).

Can this be fixed? Or is it a known issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to preserve hyperlinks in included pdf?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14620/how-to-preserve-hyperlinks-in-included-pdf) or [Embedding a pdf file with clickable external links into a LaTeX document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26128/embedding-a-pdf-file-with-clickable-external-links-into-a-latex-document)

Comment: @diabonas Sorry, I missed that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, hyperlinks are broken by `\includepdf`.
Quoting the `pdfpages` manual:

> Links and other interactive features of PDF documents When including
>   pages of a PDF only the so called content stream of these pages is
>   copied but no links. Up to now there are no TeX-engines (pdfTeX,
>   XeTeX, ...) available that can copy links or other interactive
>   features of a PDF document, too. Thus, all kinds of links will get
>   lost during inclusion. (Using `\includepdf`, `\includegraphics`, or other
>   low-level commands.) However, there’s a gleam of hope. Some links may
>   be extracted and later reinserted by a package called `pax` which can be
>   downloaded from CTAN [3]. Have a look at it!

Here is the link for [PDFAnnotExtractor (PAX)](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pax/)

Comment: It is fixed in ConTeXt mkIV.

Comment: @MartinSchröder, do you mean it work out of the box in context? Is there a chance that this will work in pdflatex/lualatex? The PAX route seems to complicated to be practical.

Comment: @alC: AFAIK ConTeXt basically reimplements the pdf inclusion in Lua. This could be made to work with LuaLaTeX, but nobody has done that yet.