# Merging tex files to make one big pdf, but need to keep the formatting in each tex file the same

Tags: input, pdfpages, include

I'm wanting to merge three `.tex` files together in a way that allows the formatting of each file to remain the same. So I want each file to show in the exact same way as they show when I view them individually.

I've tried using functions such as `\input`, `\include` and `\pdfpages`. But they all seem to change the section numbers, section heading sizes and other aspects.

I've tried downloading each `.tex` file as a pdf, then including the pdf version in the main `.tex` file, but it still changes the section numbers, etc.

I'm wanting to have one main file so that I can then add page numbers for the whole thing.

Comment: Why don't you take the three pdfs and join these? This way you can be sure that the three tex files don't influence each other.

Comment: @gernot. This is what I usually do, but gets annoying having to edit the page numbers. I wanted to see if there was a simple way to do this in latex.

Comment: There is certainly no simple way in TeX. After the end of the first document, you would have to reset everything to its initial state (except page numbers), modify `\end{document}` not to end the process, and moreover disable page numbering in the remaining documents. You would have to deal somehow with identical labels in different documents and many more things.

Comment: Have you tried the package `pdfpages`? See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77751/110998

Comment: It's not clear to me whether your are talking about the LaTeX package `pdfpages`, because it does not change section numbers or font size.