# How to prevent confproc package from linking Main file with included files

Tags: errors, packages, templates

This problem was discussed at:

I need merging several research papers in single .pdf file

[! LaTeX Error: Control sequence \sep: already defined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700010/latex-error-control-sequence-sep-already-defined)

I tried some packages (`combine`, `docmute`, `subfiles`, `standalone`) for merging several research papers compiled using CAS-DC Elsevier template in single .pdf file with bibliography in each research paper and consecutive page numbering across the whole .pdf document.

I tried ordinary `\input` `\include` commands.

Regardless package while compiling main document I always see the same error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Control sequence \sep: already defined.
```

In compiled main document I see repetition of Title, Authors, Affilations etc.

For instance: In main file in second research paper there are Title, Authors, Affilations, e-mails ORCID etc. from first research paper etc.

Exceptionally `confproc` packege does not invoke this error: `\sep`: already defined.

Сonsequently confproc packege does not invoke repetition of Title, Authors, Affilations etc.

So, I can work with this package because all requuiremets are kept. For instance there are no errors, there are no above mentioned repetitions.

However, `confproc` package invokes linking Main file with included files.

My question : how to prevent confproc package from linking Main file with included files.

All your suggestions will be appreciated.
Thank your in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by `linking` in this context? latex has no linker in the sense of the linker for a compiler and I can not guess any other meaning here.

Comment: Dear  David Carlisle, thank you for your comment.
By linking I means opening sub documents.
As I wrote: I need merging several research papers compiled using CAS-DC Elsevier template in single pdf document: 
Consecutive page numbering across the whole .pdf document should be respected.
Preserving all crossreferens and backrefernces : (bibliogrphy, footnotes, etc.) should be respected. 
Preserving CAS-DC style for each document should be respected.

Comment: I tried to include papers changing Title to Part but CAS-DC it is article template so it does not support Parts or Chapter.
Concatenating problem resolved using PDF-XChange Editor and Adobe Acrobat DC Pro.

However, in my subdocumets there are a lot of crosreferences, using PDF-XChange Editor and Adobe Acrobat DC Pro I have to remake them manually.
So, It is not about Concatenating I need problem resolution by means of LaTex (MiKTeX, TeXstudio).

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong. Yes, Article supports Parts. There are no errors. 
By linking I means opening sub documents by confproc package. 
However, the problem of repeating of Titles Authors and Affiliations is not solved.
Concatenating problem resolved using PDF-XChange Editor and Adobe Acrobat DC Pro.

However, in my subdocumets there are a lot of crosreferences and backreferences (bibliography, footnotes, etc.), using PDF-XChange Editor and Adobe Acrobat DC Pro I have to remake them manually. It takes a lot of time.

Comment: I accept any approach any package allowing me problem resolution (repeating of Titles Authors and Affiliations) by means of LaTex (MiKTeX, TeXstudio).
So, I have tried cofproc package there are no such problems .
However, there is another problem: cofproc package invoke opening subdocuments.
Is it possible to prevent confproc package from opening subdocuments?
This would be the solution to the problem.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: For merging I tried next approaches:
1) Concatenating these approaches resolve merging problem. However, in my subdocuments there are a lot of cross-references and backreferences (bibliography, footnotes, etc.), using PDF-XChange Editor and Adobe Acrobat DC Pro I have to remake them manually. It takes a lot of time.

2) simple including and inputting;
3) docmute, combine, standalone, subfiles.

Comment: I can resolve merging problem using these packages but in all articles there are repetition of Titles, Authors and Affiliations. Each subsequent article repeats the Titles, Authors and Affiliations from previous articles.

Only confpoc package does not.
However, confpoc package invokes opening subdocuments.

Comment: Is it possible to prevent confproc package from opening subdocuments?
This would be the solution to the problem.
Thank you in advance.