# How to avoid repeating Tiles and whole information about Authors in single PDF file?

Tags: templates

I essays to merge several CAS-DC articles in single PDF document.
Used approaches:

1. Concatenating: this approach resolve merging problem. However, in my subdocuments there are a lot of cross-references and backreferences (bibliography, footnotes, etc.), using PDF-XChange Editor and Adobe Acrobat DC Pro I have to remake them manually. It takes a lot of time.
2. simple including or inputting;
3. docmute, combine, standalone, subfiles etc.

I can resolve merging problem using these approaches but in all articles there are repetitions of Tiles and whole information about Authors. Each subsequent article repeats Tiles and whole information about Authors from all previous articles.
I need problem resolution by means of LaTex (MiKTeX, TeXstudio).

I include all necessary packages in my own style file in order to make my preamble more brief.
I verified my style file and have deleted all unnecessary packages.
The code of my main and included files are here [! LaTeX Error: Control sequence \sep: already defined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700010/latex-error-control-sequence-sep-already-defined)

The simplest way is including or inputting approach.

Thanks to code of Ulrike Fischer

The problem of LaTeX Error: Control sequence \sep: already defined is resolved. Now, there is no Error message.
Question: How to avoid repeating Tiles and whole information about Authors in single PDF file?
All suggestions will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.